# Python while loop return Nth letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, loops

I have a list of strings

```
X=['kmo','catlin','mept']
```

I was trying to write a loop that would return a list that contains lists of every Nth letter of each word:

```
[['k','c','m'], ['m','a','e'],['o','t','p']]
```

But all the methods I tried only returned a list of all the letters returned consecutively in one list:

```
['k','m','o','c','a','t','l','i'.....'t']
```

Here is one version of my code:

```
def letters(X):
    prefix=[]
    for i in X:
      j=0
      while j < len(i):
        while j < len(i):
          prefix.append(i[j])
          break
        j+=1
    return prefix
```

I know I'm looping within each word, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Comment: What should happen to words with a longer length than others?

Comment: Looks like you're after a form of round-robin... do you really need to use `while` loops doing this or could you just use: `res = list(zip(*X))`? That'll work if you don't care about "missing" some data as @Sayse is suggesting

Comment: I think it is clear that the intended behavior is to stop after the shortest string terminates as demonstrated by their expected output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the length of the resulting list is dictated by the length of the smallest string in the original list. If that is indeed the case, you could simply do it like this:

```
X = ['kmo','catlin','mept']

l = len(min(X, key=len))

res = [[x[i] for x in X] for i in range(l)]
```

which returns:

```
print(res)  # -> [['k', 'c', 'm'], ['m', 'a', 'e'], ['o', 't', 'p']]
```

or the even simpler (kudos @JonClemens):

```
res = [list(el) for el in zip(*X)]
```

with the same result. Note that this works because `zip` automatically stops iterating as soon as one of its elements is depleted.

---

If you want to *fill the blanks* so to speak, `itertools` has got your back with its `zip_longest` method. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for more information. The `fillvalue` can be anything you chose; here, `'-'` is used to demonstrate the use. An empty string `''` might be a better option for *production code*.

```
res = list(zip_longest(*X, fillvalue = '-'))
print(res)  # -> [('k', 'c', 'm'), ('m', 'a', 'e'), ('o', 't', 'p'), ('-', 'l', 't'), ('-', 'i', '-'), ('-', 'n', '-')]
```

Comment: Or just `res = [list(el) for el in zip(*X)]` and not worry about the length check

Comment: While I realise you're using `-` to show clearly where something is missing, I'd probably bet tempted to use the `''` empty string as the fill value (as that might be more convient if wanting to join the sub-lists later or leave it as `None`) as that could never be confused with an actual character in the string itself if one should want to identify the missing values later

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip`.

```
output=list(zip(*X))
print(output)
```

`*X` will unpack all the elements present in `X`.

After unpacking I'm zipping all of them together. The `zip()` function returns a **zip** object, which is an **iterator** of **tuples** where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator are paired together etc. Finally, I wrapped everything in a list using `list`.

---

output

```
[('k', 'c', 'm'), ('m', 'a', 'e'), ('o', 't', 'p')]
```

---

If you want `output` to be a list of lists. Then use `map`.

```
output=list(map(list,zip(*X)))
print(output)
```

---

output

```
[['k', 'c', 'm'], ['m', 'a', 'e'], ['o', 't', 'p']]
```

Comment: Love the elegant solution (although it isn't very readable if you're not fluent in Python)

Comment: @shayelk Thanks, I will add the explanation to it right away

Comment: What I meant was that while leaving such "out of the box" solutions in your code does look cool, it might be hard to understand for someone else who will need to maintain it in the future. The more straight forward solution `[[x[i] for x in X] for i in range(l)]` is much more self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> X=['kmo','catlin','mept']
> y = []
> j=0
>
> for i in X:
>     item =''
>     for element in X :
>
>         if (len(element) > j):
>             item = item + element[j]
>
>
>     y.append(item)
>     j=j+1
> print("X = [",X,"]")
> print("Y = [",y,"]")
> ```

[image: result]

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
def letters(X):
    prefix=[]
    # First lets zip the list element
    zip_elemets =  zip(*X)

    for element in zip_elemets:
        prefix.append(list(element))

    return prefix
```